# check req.body.property.childProperty inside req.checkBody()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In nodejs we commonly do something like:

```
req.checkBody('name', 'Group name is required.').notEmpty();
```

Similarly, I have done something like this:

```
req.checkBody('parent.name', 'Parent Name and group name should be different.').checkEquality(name);
```

Here check equality is a function defined in middleware like this:

```
app.use(expressValidator({
    customValidators: {
        checkEquality: function(firstInput, secondInput) {
            return firstInput.toLowerCase() != secondInput.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
}));
```

As you can see in the above code that checkEquality is just a function which returns if firstInput is equal to secondInput.

**If req.body.parent is an object then**

Every thing goes right and all validations pass or fail successfully as needed.

**If req.body.parent is string then**

I get an error saying firstInput.toLowerCase() is not a function.

The error is somewhat confusing but I know what the error mean: The error means that firstInput is undefined and undefined does not have a function toLowerCase.

Also, I understand that if req.body.parent is a string then parent.name will always be undefined.

**So, I tried:**

```
req.checkBody(('parent.name' == undefined ? 'parent' : 'parent.name'), 'Parent Name and group name should be different.').checkEquality(name);
```

But still no luck. Getting same errors.

I mean still using this code, if req.body.parent is an object I get everything going smoothly. But if req.body.parent is a string then everything is bad and gives errors as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was rather simpler than I thought:

I need to check it first like this:

```
if(req.body.parent.name == undefined) { //That means parent is a string
    req.checkBody('parent', 'Parent Name and group name should be different.').checkEquality(name);
} else { //That means parent is an object
    req.checkBody('parent.name', 'Parent Name and group name should be different.').checkEquality(name);
}
```